# Set log4j output files for a web project: issue with destination folder

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to set up log4j and I would like output files to be placed in my project, specifically in the src/main/resources/logs folder,  as I am in the development phase and I prefer having it immediately visible in my IDE. 
My issue is that I **don't want** to use **absolute paths** nor **variables** to pass as arguments when running the program (system or VM).

I have 2 questions:
1) How to set up log4j via properties to place the log files in the said folder?
2) Where to do you generally your log files?

My current log4j configuration:

```
log4j.debug=true

log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File = ${classpath}:\\logs\\log_1.txt
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush = true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold = debug  
log4j.appender.FILE.Append = false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=application.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) src/main/resources will not exist after your project is built to a war.  Files located in src/main/resource are packaged (by maven) into the WEB-INF/classes directory of your war file. src/main/resources is meant for project resource files (e.g., log4j.properties, ini config files) that need to be in the application class path. The application class path is generally not accessible through your operating system's file system.

2) Log files generally go into the log directory of your servlet container. For example, in tomcat they go in $CATALINA_HOME/logs.  The next choice is the operating system log directory.  For example in linux, /var/log/tomcat7

Comment: I understand that.  I added one more piece of information: I am  in the development phase, so I would like an easy way to access the log.

Comment: There is no portable way do do what you ask since the location of your project is unknown to the servlet container. Since you are in development, an absolute or relative path (could be retrieved from an environment variable) is acceptable, and probably the only option.